# Program flow, fork() with logic

Tags: fork

I am trying to understand the flow of this simple C fork() code:

```
fork() && fork() || fork();
fork();
printf("forked ");
```

Output for me (g++) is:

```
forked forked forked forked forked forked forked forked forked
```

Stepping over it doesn't really help me in understanding it.

Comment: You can wrap `fork()` with a function that has another side-effect. This can help you track what's going on better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fork() && fork() || fork();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Parent forks a child with return value 0 for the child process. 
Since it is logical AND operator, the short-circuit evaluation applies, 
so the child doesn’t go further. Parent goes on forking again(right-hand-side of AND). 
There are 3 processes being composed of 2 children and 1 parent.



fork() && fork() || fork();
                    ^^^^^^
                    Again parent forks one more and since OR operator
                    doesn’t apply short-circuit for latter child
                    (due to return type which is 0 and left-hand-side of OR op.), 
                    the latter child forks as well. There are totally 5 processes.

 fork()[fourth]; doubles prior number of processes 5*2 = 10 processes totally exist.
```

Your output highly likely buffered. Try `fprintf(stderr, "forked ");`, `fflush(stdout)` or `printf("forked\n”);`.

---

I think the following drawing helps more.
[image]

Comment: This is no doubt a great answer, but I'm very stupid. Could you possibly break down just `fork() && fork(); fprintf(stderr, "forked\n");` for me? Just this, considered on it's own with no other code around it.

Comment: @sid [Nominal Animal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475978/nominal-animal) my master says _every person is human being, everybody can be stuck sometimes_, don’t behave yourself bad. It will print _forked_ 3 times. 2 times at the beginning(left-hand-side of AND operator). One of the result of fork is 0 which is returned by the child, the other is not 0(that is, it is parent). The parent evaluates right-hand-side of AND operator and forks a one more child. That’s why there are two children and 1 parent as a result of `fork() && fork();`. The first child ain’t evaluate RHS of the AND operator.

Comment: @sid  En passant, I think it is nice question as well as even most-experienced guys can do mistake in this question.